I have been trying to install ms_graph python module in miniconda (conda) and receiving
After installing msgraph in miniconda via: pip install msgraph-sdk
I run my python code and receive:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Documents\user.py", line 2, in <module>
from msgraph.core import GraphClient
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'msgraph.core'

How can I fix this in a miniconda environment?

This question is similar to: Import "msgraph.core" could not be resolved - Help me search my OneDrive for Duplicates M365 Home Edition. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

GraphClient is no longer supported....
